# What is the best practice for implementing AutoSize on custom controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autosize

What is the best practice to implement autosizing on custom Windows Forms controls? For instance, a custom Label control inheriting from the System.Windows.Forms.Label class.

The Control.ClientSize article on MSDN has an example on how to set the new size (using the ClientSize property), but it doesn't give a hint on what events this method should be called:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize.aspx

I tried different methods without success (ex: overriding SizeFromClientSize, OnTextChanged, etc.). It seems that as soon as the AutoSize property is true, I cannot override the ClientSize value successfully.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better derive your control directly from `Control`, which has no `AutoSize` property and no related logic which interferes with your own logic.

Comment: I guess that's a solution... however, which events should I override to call the method to resize the control? OnTextChanged? I'm afraid that if I add it to the Resize event, I will create an endless loop...

Comment: I you have a custom control you probably implement your own Paint logic. Is it not enough to react on the new size in `OnPaint`?

Comment: In fact, the control already has a custom OnPaint event. Is resizing the control automatically in the OnPaint event enough or should it be done elsewhere?

Comment: If you have a `UserControl`, i.e. a control which hosts child-controls, then you might have to recalculate the placement of the child controls, if the standard mechanisms yield not the expected behavior; however, if your control behaves as expected, what else should you do?

Comment: OK, I'l try that and come back to accept your answer if it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Works fine! Had to add the `ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor` value to the `SetStyle` method in my constructor to add support for transparent backgrounds.